# What difference does add method make over setContentPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

This code,outputs a frame with a button placed over an image. If I change a statement from `fr.setContentPane( new JPanel...`  to `fr.add(new JPanel...`, I only see the button with size of `700,700`. What is the difference ?

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            JFrame fr = new JFrame();
            fr.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\javaapplication1\\meaning.JPG"));
                @Override
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                   super.paintComponent(g);
                   g.drawImage(image, 0,0,700,700, this);

                 }
            });
            fr.add(new JButton("Press Me"));
            fr.setSize(700,700);
            fr.setVisible(true);
            fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            fr.setResizable(false);
        }catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`JFrame#add` basically calls `JFrame#getContentPane().add`, so it's just shorthand.

So your code is actually saying...

```
fr.setContentPane(new JPanel() {...});
fr.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Press Me"));
```

Now, when you comment out the `setContentPane` line, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, the button is now being laid out in the `CENTER` position of the (frame's default) content pane and is filling the entire available space.

You could get the same effect as your original code by calling...

```
JPanel background = new JPanel() {...};
background.add(new JButton("Press Me"));
fr.add(background);
```

Take a look at [Using top-level containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details